# Can someone please explain this date - 2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z?

Tags: javascript, utc

First of all, I am new to javascript and hence if my question doesn't make any sense, please pardon me.

I want to know what exactly this date represents : `2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z`

Here, it is understood that year is 2022, month is Feb and date is 28th. After that, it showing hour as 00, minutes as 00, seconds as 00 and milliseconds as 000.
So, will it be 12 midnight of 28th, 12 midnight of 27th of Feb or something else?

I am asking this question because I have to filter some date based on date range. Suppose, I want the data from 11 to 20th of Feb 2022, then should I take toDate as 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z or 2022-02-20T23:59.59.999Z ??

Comment: It's simple 00 hrs of 28th at night, when date change from 27th to 28th

Comment: In a 24 hour clock the time goes from 00:00.000 to 23:59.999. So 00:00.000 is the beginning of the day. For this special timestamp it's the beginning of 2022-02-28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, will it be 12 midnight of 28th, 12 midnight of 27th of Feb or
> something else?

`2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z` will be considered as the **28th** midnight.

Let's look at this with an example:

```
//Date: 30th
var endDate = Date.parse("2022-07-30T00:00:00.000Z");

//Date: 29th
var currentDate = Date.parse("2022-07-29T11:59:59.999Z");

//Return true
console.log(endDate > currentDate);
```

The endDate is considered greater than the currentDate.

```
//Date 30th 
 var endDate = Date.parse("2022-07-30T00:00:00.000Z");

//Date: 30th, Time:1/1000th of a second  
 var currentDate = Date.parse("2022-07-30T00:00:00.001Z");

//Return false 
console.log(endDate > currentDate);
```

When current DateTime is .001Z greater than endDate. CurrentDate is considered greater than end date. Hence false.

Coming to your question,

> Suppose, I want the data from 11 to 20th of Feb 2022, then should I
> take toDate as 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z or 2022-02-20T23:59.59.999Z ??

If you want to **also** consider the data that was created between
`2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z` and `2022-02-20T23:59.59.999Z`. That is, on the day of 20th Feb 2022. You need have condition as `date <= 2022-02-20T23:59.59.999Z` or  `date < 2022-02-21T00:00.00.000Z`

Or

If you want to consider the data that was created **till** `2022-02-19T23:59.59.999Z`. That is, till the end of the day of 19th Feb 2022. You can have condition as `date <= 2022-02-19T23:59.59.999Z` or `date < 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score -1):

the last zeros means that your datatype is for date column is current time stamp it will inserted automatically date with hour mins and secs.
if you want to fetch just date then the query will be like follow:
SELECT * date(`column_name`) AS `shor_date` FROM table_name;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).